# IServiceProvider resolve dynamic type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, .net-5, service-provider

I am trying to resolve a service in a dynamic way. I have a bunch of model classes and for each a custom geneator class. Now if I add new models I have to add a generator for this type, which is quiet okay, because every models has other properties and needs to be generated in a different way. My problem here is, that I have an abstract generated which generates the model by it's input. Here's an example:

```cs
    // The following classes and interfaces are just examples 
    public interface IGenerator<T> where T : IModel
    {
        T Generate(string someInput);
    }

    public class Model_1_Generator : IGenerator<Model1>
    {
        Model_1 Generate(string someInput){ ... }
    }

    public interface IModel
    {
    }

    public class Model_1 : IModel
    {
    }


    private IModel GenerateModel(Type modelType, string someInput)
        {
            if (modelType == typeof(Model_1))
            {
                return _model_1_Generator.Generate(someInput);
            }

            if (modelType == typeof(Model_2))
            {
                return _model_2_Generator.Generate(someInput);
            }

            if (modelType == typeof(Model_3))
            {
                return _model_3_Generator.Generate(someInput);
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException($"Type {modelType} is not implemented yet");
        }
```

*Note: I changed the names of the services and models to make it more understandable*

This way I have to extend the method `GenerateModel(Type)` every time I add new Model types. Now I want to "simplify" this by dynamically resolving the generator by the given type:

```
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    private IModel GenerateModel(Type modelType)
        {
            // This is the problematic line
            var generator = _services.GetService<IGenerator<modelType>>();

            return generator.Generate();
        }
```

The problem is, that I cannot resolve the services because the type is a variable.
Is there a way to resolve the service by a given type

Comment: Is that dotnet core ? Which version?

Comment: I updated the tags, now you see it's .Net 5

Comment: Actually, if you read the docs, that's an antipattern (Service Locator). But did you consider [Activator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: Yes I already thought about the Activator, but this results in the same problem: I cannot instantiate a class with a variable type

Comment: Ah, I see. You'd need to Map from ModelType to ModelGeneratorType ...

Comment: Exactly. I pass the `Type modelType` as parameter into the `GenerateModel` method, but I am not able to resolve the service for `IGenerator<Type>`

Comment: This isn't a question about dependency injection. It's a question about how Generics work in C#.

Comment: In detail, yes. But I explicitly tagged it with `dependency-injection` because maybe there is a better way to solve this